# Notify dataset changed not fetching new data for the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a recyclerview that is not updating and I am not sure why:

In my main fragment I get the data for the my recyclerview in oncreateview like this:

```
    alarms = AlarmCollection.getAlarms(getActivity());
```

and then I set the adapter like this:

```
    // Adapter
    adapter = new AlarmsAdapter(getActivity(), alarms);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And then I reset the data on a timertask/runnable to update the values of on the recyclerview (they are alarms so they change once a minute).

This is done through a simple notify datasetchanged:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is though as you can see above I load the data through AlarmCollection. This is grabbing the list from the shared preferences.

But when I am calling notify dataset changed this is not being called again.

I was under the impression that when you call notify ect on a recyclerview it would update the list  or does it pureley update the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GpRyan mentioned, the problem lies in this line :

```
alarms = AlarmCollection.getAlarms(getActivity());
```

Every time you make a new instance of `alarms`.But the adapter is looking for changes in the instance of `alarms` you passed to it. so it won't work.

what you should do is removing all items from `alarms` and add your new data again.

```
alarms.removeAll();
alarms.addAll(AlarmCollection.getAlarms(getActivity()));
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

> **NOTE:** Update the `alarms`in your main thread. Once, it takes me a long time that i understand updating the data set in another thread
>   wont work with adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If your `getItemCount()` returns 0, then `notifyDataSetChanged()` won't do anything.

make sure you have added `getItemCount()` in your `RecyclerView` Adapter.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return alarms.size();
}
```

**EDIT :** you can also use `notifyitemrangechanged`

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0,alarms.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` only updates the view. Typically what you'll do is call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you've modified the data that the adapter holds (in your case `alarms`.

So what you should be doing is: updating `alarms` inside of your timer task / runnable, and then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I'll also mention that this works because the adapter is pointing to the reference of `alarms,` so when it changes (adds, removes, etc), you just need to let the UI know that it did so